# Divide entire PHP associative array equally based on a key item value

Tags: php, html

My first post here. New to PHP and I have part of what I need to do working. Making a webpage where parts can be quickly scanned into arrays using a connected barcode scanner.

```
<form id="results" action="launchresults.php" method="post"></form>
<form id="partslist" action='' method='post'></form>

<input type="text" name="partlist" id="partlist" form="partslist" />
<input type="submit" name='additem' value="Add Item" form="partslist" />
<input type="submit" name="clear" value="clear" form="partslist" />

<?php if (isset($_POST['additem'])) {
   if(!array_key_exists("parts", $_SESSION)) {
      $_SESSION["parts"] = array();
   }
   if(array_key_exists("parts", $_SESSION) && array_key_exists($_POST['partlist'],$_SESSION["parts"])) {
      $increasevalue = $_SESSION["parts"][$_POST['partlist']]['quantity'];
      $_SESSION["parts"][$_POST['partlist']]['quantity'] = $increasevalue+1;
   }
   else {   
      $_SESSION["parts"][$_POST['partlist']] = array("quantity" => 1);
   }
}

if(isset($_POST['clear'])) {
   $_SESSION = array();
}

if(array_key_exists("parts", $_SESSION)):
   foreach ($_SESSION["parts"] as $partlist => $partlist_quantity):
      foreach ($partlist_quantity as $key => $value): ?>
         <input type="text" name="items[]" value="<?php echo $partlist; ?>" />
         <input type="number" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
      <?php endforeach; ?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<input type="submit" name="submit" form="results" />
```

I can scan part barcodes in to build my arrays. If the part is something I have already scanned, it increments the quantity by 1. The input fields are editable, but the code does not currently allow updating those fields manually. When I click Submit, I end up with something like this:

```
    Array
(
    [parts] => Array
        (
            [12345] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 6
                )

            [errrt] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 2
                )

            [ffggg] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 4
                )

            [wefewf] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 10
                )

        )

)
```

What I am trying to figure out now is how to find a key part, look at the quantity for that part, and then divide everything by that value into equal arrays. So, of the main part above was 'errrt', then I would want to divide everything by 2 and end up with something that looks like this...

```
Array
(
    [errrt1] => Array
        (
            [12345] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 3
                )

            [ffggg] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 2
                )

            [wefewf] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 5
                )

        )
    [errrt2] => Array
        (
            [12345] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 3
                )

            [ffggg] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 2
                )

            [wefewf] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 5
                )

        )
)
```

This obviously needs to work for any quantity. I will need to generate an error if all of the parts entered do not divide equally based on the key value.

Comment: Just a few things, if your going to post sample data, could you use `var_export` as it creates arrays that can be used in code.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$a = array (
    'parts' => 
    array (
        12345 => 
        array (
            'quantity' => 6
        ),
        'errrt' => 
        array (
            'quantity' => 2
        ),
        'ffggg' => 
        array (
            'quantity' => 4
        ),
        'wefewf' => 
        array (
            'quantity' => 10
        )
    )
);

$choice = 'errrt';
//localize
$parts = $a['parts'];

//localize chosen 
$qty_chosen = isset($parts[$choice], $parts[$choice]['quantity']) ? $parts[$choice]['quantity'] : 0;

if(!$qty_chosen) die('Cannot divide by 0');

unset($parts[$choice]); //remove it
array_walk_recursive($parts, function(&$item)use($qty_chosen){
    $item = $item / $qty_chosen;
});

$result = [];
for($i=1;$i<=$qty_chosen; ++$i){
    $result[$choice.$i] = $parts;
}


print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [errrt1] => Array
        (
            [12345] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 3
                )

            [ffggg] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 2
                )

            [wefewf] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 5
                )

        )

    [errrt2] => Array
        (
            [12345] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 3
                )

            [ffggg] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 2
                )

            [wefewf] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 5
                )

        )

)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e0d25404900c9e719ecc54df8a393ec7eb517d9f)

In this case we can simply use `array_walk_recursive` for dividing the nested quantities, but if there are other elements in the arrays you won't be able to do that.

If you do have other elements you can use (in place of `array_walk_recursive`):

```
 $parts = array_map(function($item)use($qty_chosen){
    $item['quantity'] = $item['quantity'] / $qty_chosen;
    return $item;
 }, $parts);
```

Or

```
 array_walk($parts, function(&$item)use($qty_chosen){
    $item['quantity'] = $item['quantity'] / $qty_chosen;
 });
```

The difference is `array_walk` is the more "magical" of the 2 as it's not really made to update the array, where as `array_map` is specifically designed to do that.  We can do it with the `array_walk_*` function(s) but we have to pass the `$item` by reference with `&` (which is a whole other lesson).

Personally I prefer `array_map` in this case as it's a bit more readable.  If you want to get really special (or are feeling especially lazy) you can divide like this:

```
 $item['quantity'] /= $qty_chosen;
```

Which is sort of like `.=` or `+=` etc.  I never use that, I guess I don't do enough division to really think about it... ?

Anyway, hope it helps.

Comment: why would you `array_walk_recursive`, when an index access would be perfectly reasonable here, especially when you notice the drawback? ;o/

Comment: `when an index access would be perfectly reasonable here` - essentially you have to do the same thing as array walk before the for loop.  Because in the for loop you would need another loop (but you would be repeating this unnecessarily each time).  Each iteration of the for loop needs the Whole array, minus the one element, divided by `{n}` or `$parts` in my code.  So you see, it's pointless to modify this within the for loop and then we are doing it before, which is the same thing array walk does.  We would just be doing it manually.

Comment: with index access I meant instead of recursive, just `array_walk` and `$item['quantity'] = $item['quantity'] / $qty_chosen;`

Comment: it was easier to type `_recursive`. lol  In that case `array_map` is better.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = ['parts' => [
  '12345' => ['quantity' => 6],
  'errrt' => ['quantity' => 2],
  'ffggg' => ['quantity' => 4],
  'wefewf' => ['quantity' => 10],
]];

// i don't know how you determine the main part, but that's your cup of tea ;o)
$mainpart = 'errrt';

// fetching quantity of the main part:
$divider = $array['parts'][$mainpart]['quantity'];

// create the sub part, since they are all identical, 
// we make a sample "pattern", called "divided"
// (you could change the original array instead, 
// but I chose to leave it unchanged)
$divided = [];
foreach($array['parts'] as $partname => $part) {
    // the main part is not part of the pattern
    if($partname == $mainpart) {
        continue;
    }
    // if the quantity of the part is not dividable by
    // main part quantity, abort or whatever
    if($part['quantity'] % $divider != 0) {
        // echo error message or throw Exception or whatever
        // optionally set some flag and break;
        throw new Exception('part '.$partname.' has quantity that cannot be divided by '.$divider);
    }

    // fix the quantity.
    $part['quantity'] = $part['quantity'] / $divider;
    // add the part to the pattern.
    $divided[$partname] = $part;
}

$result = [];
// expand the pattern 
for($i = 1; $i <= $divider; $i++) {
    $result[$mainpart.$i] = $divided;
}


var_export($result);
```